# WarpingCorrespondence and custom DistanceFunction

Tags: functions, time-series

The Dynamic Time Warping algorithm is implemented in version 11 as WarpingDistance and WarpingCorrespondence. It allows some flexibility in terms of the distance function used -- I'm wondering if it can take a custom distance function in the same way that Nearest can take a user-defined distance. When I try it:

```
s1 = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6};
s2 = {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7}; 
f[x1_, x2_] := (x1 - x2)^2;
{n, m} = WarpingCorrespondence[s1, s2, DistanceFunction -> f];
```

the error is:

```
WarpingCorrespondence::invdist: The distance function f is not supported.
```

(I am actually interested in a non-Euclidean distance function, but thought I would keep it simple for the question). Am I somehow misunderstanding how to specify the DistanceFunction, or is there perhaps some workaround?

Comment: It support some `non-Euclidean` distance function as its *Details and Options*.I don't sure your have seem it.

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation in ***Details and Options*** indicating,any custom `DistanceFunction` is not allowed:

> WarpingCorrespondence accepts a `DistanceFunction->d` option with **settings**

We can know `Total[Abs[u-v]]/Total[Abs[u+v]]` is equivalent to the `BrayCurtisDistance` totally as its documentation,but regard this example:

```
WarpingCorrespondence[s1, s2, 
 DistanceFunction -> BrayCurtisDistance]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 
  12, 12, 13, 13, 13}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}} *)
WarpingCorrespondence[s1, s2, 
 DistanceFunction -> 
  Function[{u, v}, Total[Abs[u - v]]/Total[Abs[u + v]]]]
(*Get nothing*)
```

When we use `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` to see the interior code,we can find all trick in the `` Signal`TimeWarpingDump`iTimeWarping ``.A important code constrain this behavior

```
If[
            !MatchQ[distance,
                Alternatives[Automatic,
                    BrayCurtisDistance, CanberraDistance, EuclideanDistance, SquaredEuclideanDistance,
                    NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance, BinaryDistance, ManhattanDistance, ChessboardDistance,
                    CosineDistance, CorrelationDistance, MatchingDissimilarity, "DerivativeDistance"
                ]
            ],
            Message[Signal`TimeWarpingDump`h::invdist, distance];
            Return[$Failed]
        ]
```

We can consider get rid of this limitation to implement our custom distance function.

---

## A workaround

Since it just accept a specified list,we can make use of this feature to implement our custom distance function like this

```
Block[{BrayCurtisDistance},BrayCurtisDistance[x1_, x2_] := (x1 - x2)^2; 
 WarpingCorrespondence[s1, s2, DistanceFunction -> BrayCurtisDistance]]
```

> `{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,10,10,10,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13},{1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}}`

Of course,you can use other valid function in that list,but I have not test any side effect.use it carefully,please.

Comment: I am always in awe of people who can get *inside* Mathematica functions and bend them to your will!

Comment: Hi yode -- I don't think this succeeds in redefining the distance function. For the given s1 and s2, Euclidean distance gives different {n,m} values than Cosine distance. But if I try to redefine BrayCurtis to these two, the answer is always the same. I think the changed definition is not being transferred to the internal routine.

Comment: Yes,actually I have [realized that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/327qr.png) before your comment.But considering `Block[{CosineDistance},CosineDistance[u_,v_]:=Total[Abs[u-v]]/Total[Abs[u+v]];
CosineDistance[{a,b,c},{x,y,z}]]` work,maybe I miss something.