# How to understand a family of functions containing Option in System`Utilities`?

Tags: options, undocumented

For completing [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143802/21532),I'm digging function `WarpingCorrespondence` with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions ``.I found a piece code like

```
SameQ[
        optionValues = System`Utilities`GetOptionValues[TimeWarpingMethod,
                    Part[Options @ TimeWarpingMethod, All, 1],
                    options
                ],
                $Failed
    ]
```

But as I try,I cannot understand the usage of `` System`Utilities`GetOptionValues ``.And I found a series function with `*Option*` by

```
?System`Utilities`*Option*
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As we know,we just can get those value of option `Method` from documentation.I think those function can help a little.Can anybody give some example about how to use it?

Comment: Usage is quite self explanatory: ``System`Utilities`GetOptionValues[Panel, 
 Part[Options@Panel, All, 1], {ImageSize -> Style[Large, Red]}]``

Comment: @Kuba Thanks,hard to realize it..And do you get the mean of ``System`Utilities`GetMethodOptionValues``?

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples about how to use it

## `` System`Utilities`FilterOptions ``

Select those options in `{PlotRange, RotateLabel}`

```
System`Utilities`FilterOptions[{PlotRange, RotateLabel}, Options[Plot]]
```

> `Sequence[PlotRange->{Full,Automatic},RotateLabel->True]`

## `` System`Utilities`FilterOutOptions ``

Select those options out of  `{PlotRange, RotateLabel}`

```
System`Utilities`FilterOutOptions[{PlotRange, RotateLabel}, Options[Plot]]
```

> `Sequence[AlignmentPoint->Center,AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio,Axes->True,AxesLabel->None,AxesOrigin->Automatic...]`

## `` System`Utilities`GetOptionValues ``

From the Kuba's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144347/how-to-understand-this-series-function-with-option#comment388206_144347)

```
System`Utilities`GetOptionValues[Panel,Keys[Options@Panel], {Alignment -> 555}]
```

> `{555,Automatic,Automatic,Automatic,{},True,Panel,PanelLabel,Automatic,Automatic,0,Automatic,{},False,Automatic,False}`

And the `` System`Utilities`GetHeldOptionValues `` have a same behavior.

## `` System`Utilities`ProcessOptionNames ``

Make the key of rule be string

```
System`Utilities`ProcessOptionNames[Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> Range[4]]]
```

> `{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4}`